# Search box background on a different page template

Tags: php, functions, filters, search

I'm trying to make the search box background the same as the homepage, but for some reason there is a orange background - it doesn't use a different header.php its called within a filter the code below.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box_to_menu', 10, 2);
function add_search_box_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main nav' )
        return $items."<li class='custom-search custom-search-gradient menu-item'><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\"><i class=\"icon-search\"></i>".__('Search', 'concept7')."</a><div class=\"menu-search-form\"><form style=\"overflow:hidden;text-align:center;\" method=\"get\" id=\"searchbar\" action=" .home_url()."/ >
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"menu-search-form-input\" name=\"s\" id=\"search\" value=\"Type and hit enter ...\"/>
                </form></div></li>";

    return $items;
}
```

This is the code that generates the search box, however I can't see anything in this that changes the background colour or a condition to say if its a certain page template change the background or div element.

Here is a link to the website, my desired result is to get the navigation to look the same as the homepage on all other pages - basically remove the orange background.

```
http://79.170.44.128/new-getextra.co.uk/
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have CSS classes that take precedence in sub pages and makes the background orange. Its neither a PHP problem nor a WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 500 of your style.css reads:

```
.page-template-template-white-rev-php .custom-search .menu-search-form{
    background:#eef4f9;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Just remove the background line here to fix it.